# Cannot enable Hyper-V in Win 10 Pro, checkbox filled in "Turn Windows features on or off"

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

To begin with, I have virtualization enabled in BIOS, which confirms the output of `systeminfo.exe`.

[image]

I can't install it with DISM:

```
dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V /All
```

> The operation is complete but Microsoft-Hyper-V feature was not enabled.
>   A required parent feature may not be enabled. You can use the /enable-feature /all option to automatically enable each parent feature from the following list. If the parent feature(s) are already enabled, refer to the log file for further diagnostics.
>
> Microsoft-Hyper-V-All

[image]

In "Turn Windows features on or off" there is filled square instead of checkbox.

[image]

What do I do to turn Hyper-V on?

---

**EDIT #1**

I'm missing some updates but I don't know if it's related to my problem. It won't install KB4054517 (OS Build 16299.125) no matter what I do. I think it's been a known problem for more than a month.

[image]

Comment: Updated my answer, but I'm not sure if it's related.

Comment: Yes I did, multiple times... Google "KB4054517 problem" and you'll understand what I'm talking about.

Comment: What, are you serious? https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=KB4054517%20problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71974/discussion-between-stil-and-ramhound).

Comment: Once you install KB4056892/KB4073291 I will submit my answer.

Comment: some computers require it to be activated in the BIOS setup, check that

Comment: [KB4054517](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4056892) has a known issue, that the installation will report it failed, when it actually did not.  "Even though the update was successfully installed, Windows Update incorrectly reports that the update failed to install. To verify the installation, select Check for Updates to confirm that there are no additional updates available."

Answer (score 0):

I have reinstalled whole Win 10 from fresh ISO with newest build. It seems like a nuke option for small problem, but this is the only thing that worked for me.

Reinstalling immediately solved Hyper-V problem and failing KB4054517 update problem at same time.

I believe this is not a real answer, so I'm not going to accept it.