# Unable to install virtualbox on Windows 10

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Windows shows this error message when trying to install virtualbox

[image]

Downloaded virtualbox from this [official link](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.14/VirtualBox-6.1.14-140239-Win.exe)

Windows Specifications

> Edition   Windows 10 Enterprise Insider Preview
>
> Version   2004
>
> OS build  20215.1000
>
> Experience    Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.22800.0.0

Was able to install other programs without any issue.

Learn more takes me to this [page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4526424/windows-10-driver-cant-load-on-this-device)

How can i install virtualbox by overriding this error?

Comment: Are all your machine drivers up to date?  This version is 64-bit and should have Hardware Virtualization enabled. Do these things above, restart and try installing again. I assume your Windows 10 is the 64-bit version.

Comment: @John yes all machine drivers are up to date. Windows 10 is 64-bit version. Hardware Virtualization is enabled .I am already running VMware workstation pro 16 without any problems

Comment: I have VMware Workstation V16 running here fine as well.  The only remaining thing I can think of now is that Oracle needs to upgrade VB for 20H2 Insider (which will be released within the next 60 days).

Comment: Windows 10 Enterprise?  I am *GUESSING* that you are being blocked because VirtualBox installs device drivers.  One of these drivers won't function as long as hyper-v is enabled.  Why Enterprise?

Comment: Part of your problem is your using an Insider Preview build from the Beta branch.  The version being reported as 2004 isn't accurate. **20215 is from a branch what will become 2103.**  VirtualBox is likely incompatible with the build.  I am not sure the reason 20H2 was mentioned, 20215, isn't 20H2 it's 21H1.  VMWare working isn't relevant when the problem is with VirtualBox (VMWare Workstation 16 was recently released last week and was likely tested against 21H1).

Comment: "How can i install virtualbox by overriding this error?" - You can't;  You are using an incompatible version of Windows 10.

Comment: @Ramhound installed virtualbox after turning off hyper v ; when trying to re-enable hyper v there is filled square instead of checkbox. As stated in this question https://superuser.com/q/1287424/777184

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalled VMware > disabled hyper v > installed virtualbox > re-enabled hyper v > installed VMware again

Both VMware workstation and virtualbox are working fine as expected

The virtualbox error reappears if Microsoft Defender Application Guard feature is enabled